# How to export ES6 class in Javascript without module.exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, export

I was converting older JS code to ES6 and had React Components in a separate file looking like this

```
export const SomeReactComponent = React.createClass({
    // Class methods
})
export const SomeReactComponent2 = React.createClass({
    // Class methods
})
```

that were imported from other files like this

```
import { SomeReactComponent, SomeReactComponent2 } from './file.js'
```

and I was wondering how to export those classes if using ES6 `class` notation. Note, that I don't want to use `module.exports` nor I want to use `export default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax would look like this:

```
export class SomeReactComponent extends React.Component {
    // Class methods
}
export class SomeReactComponent2 extends React.Component {
    // Class methods
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00 good spot, was meant to illustrate it as two classes